# MS CRM hierarchy for contacts has wrong links to contacts photo

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015, dynamics-crm-365

We've updated CRM from on-premis CRM 2015 (7.0.2.53) to on-premis CRM 365 Version 1612(8.2.28.11)
And now we have problems with hierarchy for contacts.
Users can't see contacts photo in hierarchy.

The problem is that link to contact photo in hierarchy has an extra organization name in it:
https://orgname.crm2015.org/orgname/Image/download.aspx?Entity=contact&Attribute=entityimage&Id=c360a468-2786-e611-8103-005056ac126a&Timestamp=63741729758347400.

But link to this photo in contact itself is like this:
https://orgname.crm2015.org/Image/download.aspx?Entity=contact&Attribute=entityimage&Id=c360a468-2786-e611-8103-005056ac126a&Timestamp=63741729758347400
And it's working fine, image opens.

The question is why the link in hierarchy is wrong, why it has an extra organization name? And how it can be fixed?